# Versioning Database

Tags: mysql, database, hibernate

we are currently disguessing our Versioning Strategy.
We looked at the Hibernate Envers and first it looked helpful for us.

But now we are heading to a problem that caused by our complex data structure.

We have much table that we want to versioning that are referencing each other.

`Foo` is referencing to `bar` and multiple times to `user`. All of these Table should become an history table like 'Foo_log','bar_log' and `user_log`. 
With hibernate Envers this works fine, it creates the log tables like the original ones and creates an revision table. The log table have the revision ID and the revision Type.

Our problem is now that we would like to be able to create new Entries for the past and with that our current strategy doesn't work anymore.

**Example 1:**

`Foo` should be created for the past, let's say 01.01.2015. The referenced `bar` and 'user's should be the Entry that's active on 01.01.2015.

**Example 2:**

`Foo` should be created for the past, let's say 01.01.2015.

An new `bar` should be created also for 01.01.2015 and be referenced in `Foo`.

`user` should be the Entry that's active on 01.01.2015.

Our idea is to find the next Revision ID by the date 01.01.2015 and fetch the referenced Entries by that Revision ID. This only works when we are able to create Revision ID's in between.

**Revision Info:**

```
| REV ID   |   DateTime  |
+----------+-------------+
| 1        |  01.01.2001 |
| 2        |  01.01.2002 |
| 3        |  01.01.2004 |
| 4        |  01.01.2011 |
```

Now we have to create an Revision for 01.01.2009, to be able to we must set steps for the Revision ID:

**Revision Info:**

```
| REV ID   |   DateTime  |
+----------+-------------+
| 1        |  01.01.2001 |
| 11       |  01.01.2002 |
| 21       |  01.01.2004 |
| 31       |  01.01.2011 |
```

Now we could create an entry for 01.01.2009 with REV ID 22.
This has the problem that we are maybe running out of REV ID's to create entries in the past.

Do you have any suggestions or another idea?